# Unable to open Two page on same url in jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I  am working on Jhipster Project Version 0.11.1.In this version i have create over mapping from StaticResourcesProductionFilter.java from open two page on "/" url i.e index page and home page and it work fine in version 0.11.1.

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
        String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        requestURI = StringUtils.substringAfter(requestURI, contextPath);
        if (StringUtils.equals("/", requestURI)) {
            Authentication auth =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String name = auth.getName();
            if(name.equal("anonymousUser")){
            requestURI = "/index.html";
           }else{
            requestURI = "/home.html"; 
            }
        }
        String newURI = "/dist" + requestURI;
        request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request, response);
```

But now i have updated it to 0.18.1.Now our code is reload again again index.html not home.html i.e infinite reloading index.html page.

Please help me.